# Retry uploading same files after failed upload? - DropZone.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I use DropzoneJs - https://github.com/enyo/dropzone
I would like to resume failed uploads automatically.

I checked this issue  and there is a solution for this

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1150#issuecomment-253480122

This is my existing Dropzone config ( I tried to add the code but couldn't succeed )

```
var total_photos_counter = 0;
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    maxFilesize: 100,
    previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview').innerHTML,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Resmi Sil',
    dictFileTooBig: 'Dosya 100 MB den büyük. Daha küçük boyutlu bir fotoğraf yükleyiniz' ,
    acceptedFiles: '.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.zip',
    dictCancelUpload: 'Yüklemeyi İptal Et',
    dictInvalidFileType: "Bu tip bir dosyayı yükleyemezsiniz. Sadece resim ve Zip yükleyebilirsiniz.",
    timeout: 100000000,



    init: function () {
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
            $.post({
                url: '/images-delete',
                data: {id: file.name, _token: $('[name="_token"]').val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    total_photos_counter--;
                    $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    success: function (file, done) {
        total_photos_counter++;
        $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
    },
    error: function (file,response) {
        var dropzoneFilesCopy = dropzone.files.slice(0);
        dropzone.removeAllFiles();
        $.each(dropzoneFilesCopy, function(_, file) {
            if (file.status === Dropzone.ERROR) {
                file.status = undefined;
                file.accepted = undefined;
            }
            dropzone.addFile(file);
        });
    }
};
```

How will I add this solution into my config js. Just adding to end of file doesn't make any sense to me.

```
var dropzoneFilesCopy = dropzone.files.slice(0);
        dropzone.removeAllFiles();
        $.each(dropzoneFilesCopy, function(_, file) {
            if (file.status === Dropzone.ERROR) {
                file.status = undefined;
                file.accepted = undefined;
            }
            dropzone.addFile(file);
        });
```

Comment: use it within the `init` section like `this.on("errormultiple", function (files, response) {` i never tried it though but it should work there

Comment: Can you please share as an answer so that I can approve.

Comment: have you tried it at your end ?

Comment: do mark the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it inside the `init` section of your configuration for Dropzone, use the `errormultiple` event inside the `init` like below

```
init: function () {
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
            $.post({
                url: '/images-delete',
                data: {id: file.name, _token: $('[name="_token"]').val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    total_photos_counter--;
                    $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
                }
            });
        });

        this.on('errormultiple',function(files, response){
            var dropzoneFilesCopy = files.slice(0);
            myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
            $.each(dropzoneFilesCopy, function(_, file) {
               if (file.status === Dropzone.ERROR) {
                    file.status = undefined;
                    file.accepted = undefined;
               }
               myDropzone.addFile(file);
           });
        });
    },
```

Note : you need to change the variables accordingly inside the script that you are using.

Comment: The problem is that multiple upload is not enabled in my system. I upload them one by one. Still should I go with errormultiple? So that if a file is failed, it will retry, it will not wait others to finish.

Comment: you are using the `uploadMultiple:true` seeing the code in the configuration, i am confused a bit. but if you are not uploading multiple files you can use `error`, i have updated the code. @SNaRe

Comment: I tried both multiple and 1by1 versions. It doesn't work. Multiple would be also acceptable for me  but it didn't work as well. Can you please check my config if I forgot to change some variables inside the script. Please convert it to multiple again. It is more logical anyways.

Comment: can you be more specific when you say not woring?, any errors on console or anything. i have updated the answer please copy the script again, i have change the . `dropzone` to `myDropzone` as the instance is saved in the `myDropzone` var rather than the `dropzone` which would be undefined, and would throw an error on `dropzone.addFiles()` and `dropzone.removeAllFiles()` @SNaRe

Comment: i assume that you are saving the instance of the dropzone in the var  `myDropZone`

Comment: Yes. I implemented the code but I couldn't test it since I m not in a location that has slow internet right now. Usually I get 'Server responded with 0 code.' errors. This is why I need this. I will check tomorrow with this and let you know thanks for help.